# Generic function which can take any class member in parameter C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have several tests to do on class methods. I have difficulties using a std::function for that. 
Here an example code to simplify the problem :

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    Foo(T sum) : sum_(sum) {};
    Foo<T> method_one(const Foo<T>& foo) const { Foo<T> res(sum_ + foo.sum_); return res; }
    Foo<T> method_two(const Foo<T>& foo) const { Foo<T> res(sum_ + foo.sum_ + 10); return res; }
    Foo<T> method_three(const Foo<T>& foo, T val) const { Foo<T> res(sum_ + foo.sum_ + val); return res;}
    friend std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream & output, const Foo &foo) { output << foo.sum_; return output;}

    T sum_;
};

template<typename T>
void do_the_work(const Foo<T>& a, const Foo<T>& b, const std::function<Foo<T>(const Foo<T>&)> &func)
{
    // I do stuff before [...]
    Foo<T> c = a.func(b);
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    // I do stuff after [...]
}

int main()
{
    Foo<float> a(1.0);
    Foo<float> b(2.0);


    // I would like to replace this
    Foo<float> c = a.method_two(b);
    std::cout << c;  // 1 + 2 + 10


    // with something like that
    do_the_work(a, b, a.method_one);
    do_the_work(a, b, a.method_two);
    // and if possible make it more generic...
    do_the_work(a, b, a.method_three, 12);
}
```

I have tried using bind in the main() without success :

```
std::function<Foo<float>(const Foo<float>&)> f = std::bind(&Foo<float>::method_one, &a);
```

Any other elegant solutions would be nice. As you can notice this is to prevent redundancy of code and doing several times the "do stuff before or after"

Comment: Please, do not write solutions in the _question_. The question area is for the, um, question... If you have an adapted solution, you may post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd skip using `std::function` in the signature of `do_the_work` and resolve it all inside. It makes the inclusion of additional arguments easier:

```
template<typename T, typename Func, typename... Args>
void do_the_work(const Foo<T>& a,
                 const Foo<T>& b,
                 Func func,
                 Args&&... args)
{ 
  auto f = std::bind(func, a, b, std::forward<Args>(args)...);

  // I do stuff before [...]
  Foo<T> c = f();
  std::cout << c << std::endl;
  // I do stuff after [...]
}
```

And later

```
do_the_work(a, b, &decltype(a)::method_one);
do_the_work(a, b, &decltype(a)::method_two);
// and if possible make it more generic...
do_the_work(a, b, &decltype(a)::method_three, 12);
```

Comment: Thank you for genericity purpose I will keep your solution !

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the implicit `this` parameter to your member function, you must specify it in the `std::function` signature :

```
template<typename T>
void do_the_work(const Foo<T>& a, const Foo<T>& b, std::function<Foo<T>(const Foo<T>&, const Foo<T>&)> func)
{
    Foo<T> c = func(a, b);
    ...
}
```

Note how the `std::function` is invoked (it's not `a.foo(b)`)

And to call it :

```
do_the_work<float>(a, b, &Foo<float>::method_one);
do_the_work<float>(a, b, &Foo<float>::method_two);
```

---

If you want / can bind the object on which your functions will be called :

```
template<typename T>
void do_the_work_binded(const Foo<T>& b, std::function<Foo<T>(const Foo<T>&)> func)
{
    // I do stuff before [...]
    Foo<T> c = func(b);
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    // I do stuff after [...]
}

...

std::function<Foo<float>(const Foo<float>&)> fb = std::bind(&Foo<float>::method_one, a, std::placeholders::_1);
do_the_work_binded(b, fb);
```

**[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f969969c7bf1ec7)**

Comment: Thank you ! I really like the do_the_work_binded function. Is it also possible to add Wintermute solution in order to make it more generic ? I will try that.